# Design settings for "grouped" field

Tags: views, 10

I group by a field in a table.

The grouping is correct.
The field content is inserted as the respective heading.

Is it possible to customize this output in the design?

- Customize HTML code with the HTML elements provided: no reaction.
- Add HTML class (CSS class): nothing either.

This is probably not possible if the output format is "table"?

Best regards

Frank

Comment: How exactly did you customized the markup or CSS classes? Please update your question to add this info. Also: you flushed caches, of course, right?

Comment: yes, caches flushed.
Resulting html code looks like this:

<table class="views-table views-view-table cols-3">
      <caption>
          2013
            </caption>
I cannot address this structure, I cannot assign a CSS class to it.